# How to add unicode to a python title?

Tags: python

I'm using *python 3.5.2* and I am having trouble getting the correct unicode to show in the title.

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(b"Console Nano - v0.2a - developed by L"+u'\u00e8'+"la Null")
```

I keep getting `TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`

I want it to read `Lèla` at the end.
I'm not sure if this is part of the problem, but I am using a BATCH file to start this script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert all to byteobjects. In your example, you trying to add `b"" + u"" + ""`. In fact, you'll get same error trying to add just `b"foo" + "bar"`.

```
b"Console Nano... L" + "\u00e8".encode() + b"la Null"
```

Comment: Wow I never even thought about that. I have the wrong unicode character but I think I can fix that now that the errors are gone.